# Package managing and volume best practices in jupyter with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to create a project template with jupyter/datascience-notebook on docker, and I'm having some confusion about:

1. Have I to create a container (I use docker-compose) for each project?
2. In my project template, with the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file, I have a folder called "notebooks", that I mounted on /home/jovyan, in order to save data when I stop container, but I have also found also some cache files, is this a best practice?
3. How can I manage packages? I have to write in jupyter notebooks on top something like "! pip install xxxx", or in Dockerfile I have to write "RUN pip install xxxx", and "pip install" or "conda install"? both of these enviroments are recognized from jupyter? And if I have "requirements.txt", can I create a "requirements.pip.txt" for pip, and a "requirements.conda.txt" for conda? mhm..... Some best practice?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest
EXPOSE 8888
ENV JUPYTERLAB_ENABLED=true
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  jupyter:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    container_name: jupyter
    volumes:
      - ./notebooks:/home/jovyan
```

This is my project now
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng55d.png

Comment: Pretty sure the jupyter stacks github repo answers your question about requirements files, but they shouldn't be in the notebook unless you are wanting to re-download them every time you restart the container

Answer (score 2):

1. Unlikely that you would need to make more than 1 container unless you need to use conflicting modules.
2. Mount to a different directory, e.g. `/home/jovyan/notebooks`, and set that as your working directory in jupyter config. It may be tricky, you may want to clone my docker-compose for simple setup: https://github.com/vladiuz1/py3-jupyter-docker-compose just edit the Dockerfile and replace `minimal` with `datascience` so your desired set is setup.
3. Its best to mount `requirements.txt` with list of python packages you need. Again refer to my docker-compose to see how to do it the right way.